# Why the multiple containers pod status is Completed even when one of the containers exit with error?

Tags: kubernetes, containers, kubernetes-pod

I have a pod with multiple containers and one of them (containerA) exits with error:

```
Containers:
  containerA:
    ......
    State:          Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    1
      Started:      Fri, 27 Sep 2019 16:21:53 -0700
      Finished:     Fri, 27 Sep 2019 16:21:53 -0700
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0

  containerB:
    ......
    State:          Terminated
      Reason:       Completed
      Exit Code:    0
      Started:      Fri, 27 Sep 2019 16:21:54 -0700
      Finished:     Fri, 27 Sep 2019 16:21:59 -0700
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0

  containerC:
    ......
    State:          Terminated
      Reason:       Completed
      Exit Code:    0
      Started:      Fri, 27 Sep 2019 16:21:54 -0700
      Finished:     Fri, 27 Sep 2019 16:21:58 -0700
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
```

This pod has `restartPolicy: Never`. And it's been controlled by a Job with `backoffLimit: 9`. During all the attempts, the pod status is shown as:

```
NAME                   READY   STATUS       RESTARTS   AGE
my-pod-2scsn           0/4     Completed    0          3d18h
my-pod-8z7qq           0/4     Completed    0          3d18h
my-pod-9cjnc           0/4     Completed    0          3d18h
my-pod-f6hxr           0/4     Completed    0          3d18h
my-pod-fz7hk           0/4     Completed    0          3d18h
.....
```

This `Completed` is confusing here (one of the containers exits with Error). Why the pod status is `Completed` here?

Answer (score 0):

According to the official Kubernetes [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/), [Job](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/#handling-pod-and-container-failures) treats a Pod failed once any of entire containers quit with a non-zero exit code or for some resources overlimits detected. Due to this fact, Pod [phase](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#pod-phase) actually is the main indicator in terms of generic Pod lifecycle, telling initial Job about most recent Pod status.

However, what I have observed, that `kubectl get pod` output `STATUS` column doesn't display Pod phase status, instead  it retrieves a value for a particular container inside a  Pod  and uses `.status.containerStatuses.state.terminated.reason` field to display `STATUS` column data.

In fact, you can even get more informative output, supplying custom columns to the standard `kubectl` command-line tool:

```
$ kubectl get po -o=custom-columns=NAME:.metadata.name,PHASE:.status.phase,CONTAINERS:.spec.containers[*].name,STATUS:.status.containerStatuses[*].state.terminated.reason
```

Since Job reaches `backoffLimit: 9` count, it will terminate with `BackoffLimitExceeded` warning message:

> Warning  BackoffLimitExceeded  54m   job-controller  Job has reached
>   the specified backoff limit